Encountering 'fatal: could not resolve host github.com'
I encountered a frustrating issue while attempting to clone a repository from GitHub in my WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) environment. Whenever I try to clone a repository using the 'git clone' command, I receive the following error message:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<USER>/<REPO>/': Could not resolve host: github.com
This error suggests a problem with DNS resolution specifically for the hostname 'github.com'. Interestingly, I'm able to successfully ping other domains like 'google.com', indicating that DNS resolution is functioning for those domains. However, resolving 'github.com' fails consistently with a 'temporary failure in name resolution' error.
Methods Tried:

Checked DNS Configuration: Examined the /etc/resolv.conf file in WSL, confirming the DNS server IP address (172.21.96.1).
Verified DNS Server Reachability: Successfully pinged the DNS server (172.21.96.1) and received responses.
Attempted DNS Cache Flush: Used the sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches command to clear the DNS cache.
Tested DNS Resolution for Other Domains: Successfully pinged domains like 'google.com' without any issues.
Encountered Error Specific to 'github.com': Received a 'temporary failure in name resolution' error when attempting to ping 'github.com'.

I have also tried using these answers, but none of them work for me.
Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to resolve the DNS resolution issue specifically for 'github.com'. Any insights or suggestions on how to further troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You can enter the error that you receive in a code block (your screenshot)
